# How to pass elastic query to kibana dashboard

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-6

i have to **integrate Kibana dashboard(Iframe) with my own elastic query** .

so using **rison-node** how can i pass the elastic query into dashboard through URL.

**Followings that are i tried**:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/dashboard-search-parameter-via-url/84385/2

Comment: Can you share your dashboard URL?

Comment: @Val - i am developing in local host so i cannot able to share...i am using iframe of kibana dashbaord so how i can  pass elastic query to iframe url?

Comment: I just need to see the relative path, not the host

Comment: @Val-   http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/a4c73520-d9ca-11e8-94fa-a1829f1fc432?_g=()&_a=(description:'',filters:!(),fullScreenMode:!f,options:(darkTheme:!f,hidePanelTitles:!f,useMargins:!t),panels:!((embeddableConfig:(),gridData:(h:20,i:'1',w:16,x:0,y:32),id:'5e64a800-d9d0-11e8-94fa-a1829f1fc432',panelIndex:'1',type:visualization,version:'6.4.0'),

Comment: You'll find that you get significantly better answers if you include the content of your question here - the point of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of questions and answers, that obviously fails if the questions are contained on other sites outside the control of SO.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution. But it's a dirty one.

I would start by getting 2 URLs from the browser. First URL which links to the pure dashboard. Second, with a filter applied.

Now, compare the 2 URLs online or with a tool like BeyondCompare. This will reveal the changes required to add a filter.

*All words no code* :|

For example, I tried this on my own dashboard URL. See a part of this huge URL, that was changed.

```
filters:!(),options:(darkTheme:!f),panels:!((col:1,id:AWbJ883y-laqWN-SkuG2,panelIndex:1,row:4,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:visualization),(col:7,id:AWbJ9BBX-laqWN-SkuG3,panelIndex:2,row:1,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:vis

filters:!(('$state':(store:appState),meta:(alias:!n,disabled:!f,index:AWbJsP0d-laqWN-SkuGu,key:user.keyword,negate:!f,type:phrase,value:aditya),query:(match:(user.keyword:(query:aditya,type:phrase))))),options:(darkTheme
```

Here, as you can see the filter section is empty in the first case, while the second case does have my filter query. Now, you can easily create dynamic URLs based on this approach.

Comment: Oh. I see you already posted similar post in your question. Unfortunately, this is the best you will get. They do not support such functionality.